# How can I read password protected Word files on OS X?

Tags: macos, security, microsoft-office, passwords

I receive Word documents by mail and read them using the built-in Gmail reader.
Sometimes the documents are password protected and I need to obtain access to a Windows machine with Office installed in order to read them.

Is there a quicker / less hassle requiring method ?

I don't want to have to install Vmware / Parallels nor Office on my fresh and sterile macbook.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested Word 2003 and Word 2007 password protected files, and Open Office suite can open those types of files.  Open Office is FREE and available on Mac, Windows, etc.

Here's the download link http://download.openoffice.org/other.html#tested-full

Comment: Have you tried using open office?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to open them up in [Pages](http://www.apple.com/iwork/pages/) but I've never tried it. The other option would be to pick up a copy of [Word for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/Word2008/default.mspx).

Answer (score 1):

Or you could find a word viewer for Mac. Basically you can open word documents but can't change them if you're okay with that restriction.

Otherwise, OpenOffice is a good bet.